# Duplicate an Open Office document in a new window

Tags: openoffice

I am using Open Office 3.4.1.
Is there a way (via key combination or something) to duplicate the current document and open it in a new window?

Edit: I mean a more convenient way than pressing CTRL + a, c, n, v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this, other then using CTRL + a, c, n, v.